# Telerik- Como usar un control Upload como editor de celda en Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy usando los controles para ASP.NET MVC de Telerik, necesito usar un control Upload como editor en una celda de un grid. La idea es tener una celda para escribir una descripcion del archivo y en la otra celda el upload para seleccionar el archivo y al final guardar la informacion del grid en una tabla y subir el archivo a una ruta determinada en un servidor.
Alguien me puede orientar como puedo logar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes hacer una plantilla donde tienes el componente upload, y entonces en la columna donde quieras que aparezca poner la plantilla como un editor template. Por favor revisa el demo de telerik que ahi explica como hacer un editor template. 
Saludos